# FAQ page shows answers automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to create a drop down FAQ page with jQuery and for some reason the answers are showing when I load the page.

I have my jQuery script on my page

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
```

And my javascript page:

```
<script src="js/threecatsdesign.js"></script>
```

My full javascript is this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#categories h3").click(
        function() {
            $(this).toggleClass("minus");
            if ($(this).attr("class") != "minus") {
                $(this).next().hide();
            }
            else {
                $(this).next().show();
            }

            $("#image").attr("src", "");

            // needed for IE so a placeholder isn't displayed for the image
            $("#image").attr("style", "display:none;");     }
    ); // end click
}); // end ready
```

My HTML is this code:

```
<main id="categories">
        <h3>What is this site about?</h3>
        <div>
            <ul id="web_images">
                <li>We are a website that holds Photoshop lessons called tutorials. Please read our about me page for more information.</li>
            </ul> 
        </div>
        <h3>If you hold contests on the site, how do I enter?</h3>
        <div>
            <ul id="java_images">
                <li>Go to our page called contests in the nav bar and you will need to fill out the form in order to enter.</li>
            </ul>
        </div><p>
        <h3>I have a tutorial I would like to suggest or put up my own. How do I do that?</h3>
        <div>
            <ul id="net_images">
                <li>Please go fill out our contact form and you will be contaced with 24 hours or less on how to proceed.</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Comment: Can you include your CSS? It looks like you're toggling `.minus`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add some css to hide the questions to begin with.

```
<style>
    .faq-question div {
        display:none;
    }
</style>
```

I suggest putting this in a different file, but inline styles like this work for a quick and dirty solution.

You also should wrap each question and answer in a tag like this

```
<div class="faq-question">
    <h3>What is this site about?</h3>
    <div>
        <ul id="web_images">
            <li>We are a website that holds Photoshop lessons called tutorials. Please read our about me page for more information.</li>
        </ul> 
    </div>
</div>
```

And change your JS to reflect the change in elements.

```
$(".faq-question").click(
```

Comment: Ok I did this but the styles code hide everything where it doesn't show if you click it,

Comment: My mistake. Update the style selector to read `.faq-question div {`. I have updated my code to reflect it.

Comment: @Brittney Please check this answer if it has helped you.